# How to prevent all parents from toggling when clicking on child link jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have something like this:

[image]

And some ultra simple jQuery that is toggling the child links when I click the parents ("Spec Sheet", "Instructions" etc) although when I click on one, they all open. Here is the code (is there a simple way to only open one parent per click)?:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#dropdown-download-links li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
        var ulContainer = $(this).closest("ul");
        e.preventDefault();
        $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML

Comment: Sorry, code is partially from DB and a little sloppy but this gives you an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/3sh0qy91/

Comment: It's basically those titles you see "Spec Sheet" as one LI in a parent UL and within the LI of each there is a nested UL with two links that are supposed to toggle on click. Just not at the same time if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).closest("ul");` is targeting the wrong element, this targets the first parent `ul` encountered going up the DOM tree from the clicked  `a` tag

In the below `$(this).closest("li").find("ul");` will target the first parent `li` tag encountered going up the DOM tree from the clicked `a` tag, then find the  `ul` tag *inside* that `li` tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#dropdown-download-links li > a").unbind().click(function(e) {
    var ulContainer = $(this).closest("li").find("ul");
    e.preventDefault();
    $(ulContainer).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticky-sidebar">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="http://wacdev.waclighting.com/locator/" target="_blank" class="btn-black">Where to Buy</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <ul id="dropdown-download-links" data-sticky="sticky-aside" class="fast-links dropdown">
        <div data-domain="http://wacdev.waclighting.com" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div data-zspectempid="" style="display:none;">0</div>
        <div data-ppid="" style="display:none;">333</div>
        <div data-spec-sheet-url="" style="display:none;">/storage/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf</div>


        <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf" target="_blank">SPEC SHEET</a>

          <ul id="spec-sheet-option" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.pdf"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>Oculux Architecture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dim-to-Warm!</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf" target="_blank">INSTRUCTIONS</a>

          <ul id="spec-sheet-option" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf">Oculux Architecture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dim-to-Warm!</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/IES_FILES/Oculux Architectural_IES.zip" target="_blank">IES FILES</a>

          <ul style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf">Some value</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some other value</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/DIM_REPORT/E1806008 (R3C).pdf" target="_blank">DIMMING REPORT</a>

          <ul style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="http://192.168.12.44:8090/INST_SHEET/R3CRN-trim_0.pdf">Some value</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some other value</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @rec0nstr They are working, its just that the html you provided in the jsfiddle doesnt have any uls contained in those li tags to actually display. Here, ill add some dummy ones here to avoid confusion :)